# visual studio generates executable from C# but where are the obj files?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio Express 2010 installed, and have used it for a C# project.
Now I am writing a .gitignore file so I can exclude from git the object files that I expect to be generated.

I come from a C++ world mainly.

Trouble is, despite the fact that the target is being generated correctly I cant see any object files (with .obj or .o extension)anywhere in the directory tree of the solution.
Could this be caused by the configuration where they are being sent elsewhere?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx#vcconcommand_linebuildinganchor3

Answer (score 4):

To answer your direct question: C# doesn't have a compile step that produces `.obj` files like C and C++ do.

However, a `.gitignore` that's appropriate for C# projects is a well-solved problem.  Visual Studio will ask you if you want to add the `.gitignore` to your new git repository when you create it.  If you already have a repository, you can just use the community's [`.gitignore` for Visual Studio](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) which is excellent (and what Visual Studio would install for you.)

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any .obj files generated during compilation, but there is an obj directory under the project root that's used to store temporary files. This is the directory that should be in your .gitignore file.